# How do I configure multiple dictionary keys in a yaml file in Python?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I am trying to use a yaml file to store dictionary keys so I can parse various json payloads.

I have the following yaml file loaded into a variable called 'cfg':

```
my_table: metadata
```

When I run:

```
for i in json['resources']:
    print(i[cfg['my_table']])
```

I can see all values from my json's ['metadata'] keys just fine.

However, I would like to see all values from the **['metadata']['guid']** keys that exist under ['resources'].  So when I change my yaml file to:

```
my_table: metadata, guid
```

It doesn't work.  I've also tried these variations:

```
my_table: ['metadata', 'guid']  #tried ''.join("['{0}']".format(a) for a in cfg['my_table']) which gives me what I want, but when I shove this inside i[], I get a key error
my_table: ['metadata']['guid']  #yaml file doesn't parse properly
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Well if you trying to map the yaml properties then the value's structure should be the one which python can understand. try `my_table: [metadata, guid] `

Comment: Can we see an except of your json? Is `guid` a key of the `metadata` object or are they seperate keys in the `resources` object?

Comment: You need `i['metadata']['guid']`, which is two separate indexing operations on `i` and `i['metadata']`, not a single one that you can capture in one expression. That is, there's no `x` for which `i[x] is i['metadata']['guid']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to store dictionary keys in a yaml file?

Just do

```
# keys.yaml
my_table: [metadata, guid]
```

And then in your python file

```
keys = yaml.safe_load('keys.yaml')['my_table']

for obj in json['resources']:  # don't call it json, that's a package name
    print(obj[keys[0]][keys[1]])
```

For a variable number of keys (not only two) do it like so:

```
def recursive_getitem(obj, keys):
   if len(keys) == 0:
      return obj
   return recursive_getitem(obj[keys[0]], keys[1:])
```

and then do

```
for obj in json['resources']:  
    print(recursive_getitem(obj, keys))
```

---

To answer your second question in the comments, you need to use a nested list

```
# keys.yaml
my_table:
    - [metadata, guid]
    - [entity, name]
```

.

```
# py file
keys = yaml.safe_load('keys.yaml')['my_table']

for obj in json['resources']:  # don't call it json, that's a package name
    print(obj[keys[0][0]][keys[0][1]])
    print(obj[keys[1][0]][keys[1][1]])
```

Comment: Since the OP is using PyYAML, using `yaml.load()` is unsafe as per the PyYAML documentation. It also completely unnecessary here, `yaml.safe_load()` will do.

Comment: Fair enough, i'm not very experienced in yaml so I'll edit.

Comment: Yes, that works for me!  I can now place: [metadata, guid] in my yaml file.  By any chance, how would I get ['metadata']['guid'], then get another pair like ['entity']['name'].  If I place [[metadata, guid], [entity,name]] in my yaml file, it doesn't load properly.  That said, you answered my original question so I will accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you @FHTMitchell - is there a recursive function for a variable number of not just items in each list but # of lists?